# How to feed a local placeholder?

Tags: tensorflow, placeholder, local-variables

I would like to feed a placeholder defined in a function. The following is an simplified example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf

def CreateInference():
    x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None))
    w2 = tf.get_variable('w2', initializer=1.0)
    b2 = tf.get_variable('b2', initializer=2.0)
    y2 = w2 * x2 + b2

y2 = CreateInference()

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs', tf.get_default_graph())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
#    print (sess.run(y2, feed_dict={x2:2.0}))

writer.close()
```

The graph is correctly created as shown in the following Tensorboard graph.

[image]

The problem is that `feed_dict={x2:2.0}` doesn't work, since `x2` is a local variable used within the function CreateInference. Could anyone please tell me how to access and feed values for the variable `x2` in the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do the obvious and return references of the objects

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf

def CreateInference():
    x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None))
    w2 = tf.get_variable('w2', initializer=1.0)
    b2 = tf.get_variable('b2', initializer=2.0)
    y2 = w2 * x2 + b2
    return x2, y2

x2, y2 = CreateInference()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print (sess.run(y2, feed_dict={x2:2.0}))
```